# How to automate Id generation?

Tags: haskell

I'm working on **yesod** application which has routes like

```
/make/something MakeR POST
```

on which server generates an object and returns its ID wrapped into JSON. I use `Int` as ID.

So, I ended up using a data types like this

```
data Manager
  = Manager
  { objects :: IntMap Object
  , nextId  :: Int
  }
```

I store them in `TVar` in `App`. And each time handler for `MakeR` called, I increment `nextId` field of `Manager`.

The problem is that I have many managers like above and I want to abstract ID counter incrementation.

One idea would be to use a state monad. But, still, I have to store counter somewhere. This way it doesn't feel sound:

```
data App = App
  { ...
  , appAMap :: TVar (IntMap A)
  , appACtr :: TVar Int
  , appBMap :: TVar (IntMap B)
  , appBCtr :: TVar Int
    ...
  }
```

Is there a pattern or approach I can use in order to automate ID generation without losing soundness?

Comment: Use a string instead of int and generate it as a GUID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID generation is stateful.

I generally see two approaches to ID generation. You can either generate an ID at random in a way that is very unlikely to collide (e.g. random UUID as @Ewan suggested), or delegate to an ACID datasource to generate an ID for you. For example you could use a PostgreSQL table to generate an autoincrementing ID for you. You can store your ID in memory like you're doing, but it'll cause collisions when you restart your app, or if you have multiple instances of the app running.

You can abstract ID generation by creating an interface that is polymorphic on the type of id. I don't know Haskell, but in Scala it would be something like this (using a Monad to capture the side-effect of creating an ID):

```
trait IdGenerator[M[_], ID] {
  val generateId: M[ID]
}

class UuidIdGenerator extends IdGenerator[Task, UUID] {
  override val generateId = Task.delay(UUID.randomUUD())
}

// Thread-safe id generation for a single instance
class InMemoryIdGenerator extends IdGenerator[Task, Int] {
  private val id = new AtomicInteger(0)
  override val generateId = Task.delay(id.incrementAndGet())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Solution where I generate UUID is not what I want because it will require refactoring (maybe big). So, I guess ACID approach is fine: even if I can't store complex data in DB, I can put something related there in order to generate ID.

Comment: Also, I could use some language hacks, say, to write a function which returns specific variable for given type. But I don't feel it's right solution. Plus, IDs will be stored in memory and I'll have to save them somewhere when server shutdowns.